# How to prevent an element from losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to keep the Focus on one textbox ? even if you click anywhere in a browser.

```
$("#txtSearch").focus();
```

Comment: I'm guessing lots of coffee isn't an acceptable answer?  Are you going to force the user to press enter to submit the form?

Comment: Nah he/she's gonna touch it because im using a tablet

Answer (score 33):

You need to subscribe to the `blur` event of the `textbox` and reinstate focus with a small timeout:

```
$('#txtSearch').blur(function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () { $("#txtSearch").focus(); }, 20);
});
```

This way you don't rely on subscribing to the events of any other element on the page. If you subscribe to `body click` or `html click`, it won't run if any other element prevents propagation of its `click` event, also it won't work when tabbing out of the `textbox`.

Example:

```
<!-- I will not propagate my click to top level DOM elements -->
<button id="button">Click me</button>

<script>
$('#button').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 this is the only answer so far that handles events like tabbing out of focus.

Comment: Blur is the event that fires when the focus has been lost on an element

Comment: @Curt I included some explanation on why not to handle click.

Comment: +1 My answer doesn't taken into account tabbing, other click events etc.

Comment: Why the timeout, out of interest?

Comment: @LeonardChallis Because otherwise focus would not work. I can't quite explain why :(

Comment: @LeonardChallis : if you don't timeout, the `$("#txtSearch").focus()` will instantly (and synchronously) be applied, then the `blur` event will bubble up the tree, and the textarea will lose the focus.

Comment: AFAIK, the timeout could as well be 0, though. The important part is to apply the function *after* the `blur` event has been completely resolved.

Comment: @LeGEC Since when do the `blur` or `focus` events bubble? Your example is exactly why they don't.

Comment: The only reason is for this to run "async", not in the event handler. I have used it often and it's funny that I can't explain why it works this way.

Comment: @LeGEC You're just contradicting yourself. `blur` doesn't bubble. `focusout` does - http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ . Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/6g68C/

Comment: @Ian : I stand corrected. I have used jQuery event delegation on `blur`, so I thought the event behaved as other regular events. The last parahraph in http://api.jquery.com/blur/ mentions only Internet Explorer, so I thought it was yet another special case for IE.

Comment: @LeGEC Yeah, it's put together very confusingly. I'm betting jQuery takes care of things internally so that it makes all events "bubble", but only fires certain things if they're bound a certain way. So with your example of event delegation, when it's "bubbling" internally, it checks the event handler and sees it's delegated, so it should be executed. Something like that.

Comment: I know IE (or at least old IE) has problems with focusing the element without `setTimeout`, or at least I thought it did, and that's why I always use it. I can't find the resource I "learned" it from, but I know I wouldn't use it that way if I didn't see something like that about it

Comment: @Ian : the api doc (http://api.jquery.com/blur/) says it actually binds a listener to `focusout` when you delegate `blur` handling.

Comment: I always solve this like so -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhaLY/1/), and find it more "proper" ???

Comment: @LeGEC Psh all I needed to do was read. Well that's interesting...makes sense though

Comment: @adeneo That's nifty! Unfortunately, you can still tab away. But as for clicking, that's cool

Answer (score 9):

Konstantin Dinev answer works ok in most cases, but if you dont want to lose the focus only when clicking on certain parts of the html just do this:

```
$(".nofocus").on( "mousedown", function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

In my case i'm doing a small html text editor and i dont want to lose the control when pressing an action button, but yes in any other case.

I just need to add the nofocus class to the button and it will not take the control

Comment: Thank you! This is the ideal answer. This solution prevents the loss of focus in the first place. This is what you need if you want to manipulate `selectionStart` of a textarea. All the other answers describe how to return focus immediately after losing focus.

Comment: For me, this does the opposite. It prevents me from focusing...

Comment: For me, I had to call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent losing focus, `return false` didn't seem to do anything. https://codepen.io/TechnoSam/pen/ZEyxxvy

Answer (score 3):

```
$("html").click(function(){
   $("#txtSearch").focus();
});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QhaLY/*

Comment: *Technically* it's still possible to type in `#txtSearch2` if you're very fast.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Or if you press 'tab'

Comment: @h2ooooooo I agree with David. My answer prevents clicking anywhere else, but it doesn't prevent tab. Konstantin's answer is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible without jQuery and without re-focusing, if you just need a click on specific elements to not grab the focus

just listen for the mousedown event and cancel it

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", event => {event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation()});
```

Comment: There are other ways to lose focus, such as tabbing, as several answers mention. This may be useful for something else, but not the original question.

Comment: You're right, didn't read the original question again after I found my solution. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(){$("#txtSearch").focus();});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of loosing focus than clicking area away from the input i.e. tabbing. If you want to prevent loosing focus use blur event i.e.

```js
document.getElementById('txtSearch').addEventListener('blur', e => {
  e.target.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}` and that works just fine.